# Getting no results by NumericRangeQuery in Lucene

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I am using below code for creating index on ListingId

```
 Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = new Lucene.Net.Documents.Document();
 NumericField numberField =  new NumericField("Listing_Id", Field.Store.YES, true);
 numberField.SetDoubleValue(fieldNumber);//        .SetDoubleValue(15, 25, 21, 51, etc. );  // Here   fieldNumber I am getting from database                
 doc.Add(numberField);
```

This is code I am using in search:

```
 string indexFileLocation =  Server.MapPath("~/searchindex/");
 Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dir = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.GetDirectory(indexFileLocation,false);           
 IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(dir,true);            
 NumericRangeQuery query = NumericRangeQuery.NewDoubleRange("Listing_Id", 1, 6, true, true);
 var hits = indexSearcher.Search(query);
```

But I am getting no results in search.